# Overwrite generated restful url helpers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, helper

Lets say I have a Page resource, and a particular instance has id = 5 and permalink = foobar.

With `resources :pages` I can use `<%= link_to @page.title, @page %>` which outputs the url "/pages/5".

How would I make it output "/pages/foobar" instead? Likewise with the edit url... How do I make `edit_page_path(@page)` output "/pages/foobar/edit"?

**UPDATE**

Answers so far have said to override `to_param` in Page.rb which is a great start. +1 to each. But what if I want `<%=link_to @page.title, @page%>` to output "/:permalink" rather than "/pages/:permalink"?? I'll accept the answer that comes up with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `to_param` method in your model which will tell Rails what to use instead of your primary key for routing.

For example

```
class Page
  def to_param
    "#{self.id}-#{self.title.parameterize}"
  end
end
```

The parameterize call makes your title URL friendly, you might also notice the use of self.id, this is recommended in case you have a duplicate title.

Comment: Ahh cool. But... What if I want to path to a page to be "/:permalink" rather than "/pages/:permalink" ??

Comment: You'll have to make a custom route in your `config/routes.rb` file.  Such as `match /:permalink' => pages#show` (off the top of my head)

Comment: You can use the `:as => :foo` flag, like so `match /:permalink' => "pages#show", :as => :pages`.  However I'm not sure off the top of my head if this will *override* the `resources` use of `pages_path`.  I assume if you place this `match` call above the `resources` call it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to overide to_param method in your model to return the field you want. [Here's a blog post with some examples](http://nithinbekal.com/2010/rails-seo-friendly-urls-using-to_param/):

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a permalink.

Add this to your model:

```
class Post 

    def to_param
        "#{id}-{title}"
    end

end
```

This assumes that you have a title.

Once you get this you want to look look up [permalink-fu](https://github.com/fousa/limit-permalink-fu), or it's actually really simple to do your own with an after save:

class Post

```
before_save :manage_peramlink

def manage_peramlink
    permalink = "#{name.gsub(/\s/, '_').gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase}"
end

def to_param
    "permalink"
end
```

end

Make sure you add `peramlink` as a field to your model.